# Creating JIRA issue using curl from command line

Tags: rest, curl, jira

I've been through documentation [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-create-issue) according to which I'm creating a issue for JIRA . I know I'm making some terribly small mistake .
I'm trying to create a new JIRA request from command line (later I'll integrate in my java code)
From my Mac terminal I'm trying to run :

```
    curl -D- -u username:password -X POST --data {"fields":{"project":{"key": “PROJECTKEY"},"summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.","description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API","issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}}} -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://mycompanyname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/
```

I believe this has something to do with the "data". 
Thanks in advance. The example has been taken from the documentation link itself.

OUTPUT : I'm getting nothing in my terminal, no error, no expected output .

PROJECTKEY is taken from the KEY column from the All Project list in my DASHBOARD.

Comment: you need to put your posted data in single quotes

Comment: Can you give me a example? Thanks in advance..

Comment: `--data '{"fields": ....... }' `

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two things are off:

1. you need to put the data that you want to post in quotes
2. the first double quote surrounding PROJECT_KEY is a unicode character instead of a regular double quote, so change `“PROJECTKEY"` to `"PROJECTKEY"`

This should work:

```
curl -D- -u username:password -X POST --data '{"fields":{"project":{"key": "PROJECTKEY"},"summary": "REST ye merry gentlemen.","description": "Creating of an issue using project keys and issue type names using the REST API","issuetype": {"name": "Bug"}}}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" https://mycompanyname.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/
```

Comment: Z That was probably a mistake thanks.. But now I'm getting a error :


{"errorMessages":["Version Found: Version Found is required."],"errors":{}}

any help on this plss ??

Comment: This works for me. JIRA is created but i do not get the JIRA number (ID) in the logs. Please let me know if i'm missing anything.

Comment: Essentially, i want to store the JIRA number in a variable which can be used in the scripts for other purposes.

Comment: Above syntax was working fine for me but suddenly I've started getting this error message: `curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 202`. What am i mssing?

Comment: @Yash Try using curl's `-g` or `--globoff` option. Check the man page.